# Generate a combo chart using ngx-charts

Tags: ngx-charts

I need a combo chart between Stacked Bar Char and Line Bar Chart could you help me with some example.
I was reading this doc:
[Demo for combo charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/blob/master/demo/combo-chart/combo-chart.component.ts)

But I can't understand the example.

Comment: Hi, Frank! Did you manage to find any examples? I'm facing the same issue: ngx released 10.0 and I can find no code examples at official site.

Comment: @E.Evsevleev I found some issues using this charts package and our company decide did a migration to HighCharts.

Comment: I did manage to use combo chart and then updated to our needs (multiple bars and some more features). I will post demo later.

Comment: Thanks, @E.Evsevleev, please keep me updated.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone that chances upon this post when searching for a way to include the combo-chart, these are the main steps to use the demos from the ngx-charts GitHub.

1. Copy the all the 4 components from the combo-chart component under the demo folder in the ngx-charts repository

   - Your folder structure will look like this:

   ```
   combo-chart
    └─ combo-chart.component.scss
    └─ combo-chart.component.ts
    └─ combo-series-vertical.component.ts
    └─ index.ts
   ```
2. Change the imports in the 2 component.ts files from relative links to '@swimlane/ngx-charts'

   - From `'../../src'` to `'@swimlane/ngx-charts'`
   - From `'../../src/common/label.helper'` to `'@swimlane/ngx-charts'`
3. Import the components and declare them in your module.ts file

   ```
   .
   import { ComboChartComponent, ComboSeriesVerticalComponent } from './combo-chart';
   .
   .
   declarations: [
   .
   .
   ComboChartComponent, ComboSeriesVerticalComponent],
   .
   ```
4. You can now use the custom combo-chart component in your template with the selector `<combo-chart-component>`

I've created a simple gist walking through the process in greater detail, do check it out - https://gist.github.com/gabrielloye/67921cda6139ba1806920da2a7e2fcb2

The StackBlitz link to the working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-combo-chart

Comment: Great example unfortunately it doesn't work in Firefox (latest).